# Где лучше располагать вспомогательные функции для юнит тестов?

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, тестирование, code-style, gtest

У меня есть `Foo.h`, `Foo.cpp` и `TestFoo.cpp`. Для тестов использую gtest с классом `TestFoo : testing::Test`. Где лучше располагать вспомогательные для юнит тестов функции: внутри этого класса или вне класса в файле `TestFoo.cpp`? Кажется, что лучше функции, которые не используют ничего из gtest, располагать вне класса, а все что используют - внутри. Правда ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не особо важно, где будут вспомогательные функции для тестов, в классе `TestFoo` или где-то рядом в том же или другом модуле. Главное, чтобы этих функций не было в самом юните `Foo`, так как они не должны попадать в поставку клиенту и необходимы исключительно при разработке.

Если тесты планируется долго и часто расширять/изменять и их достаточно много, а вспомогательные функции существенно реже, то может иметь смысл выделить их в отдельный модуль, чтобы минимизировать кол-во перекомпилируемого кода и сделать проект более структурированным. Но и в этом случае важно не уйти в какой-то оверинжиниринг, создавая множество мелких модулей, которые вполне могли бы быть единым целым.